# How to fix java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-thread

In my application i want use one thread into CountDownTimer and for this i write below code.

But when run application after a few seconds show me error in LogCat.

**My codes:**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auction_detail_bid, null);
        new CountDownTimer(newCalculateTime, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (millisUntilFinished / 1000 <= newCanOfferBeforeTime) {
                    Constants.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getlast6BidData();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {

            }

        }.start();

return v;
}

    private void getlast6BidData() {
        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getUpdateBidsList(Constants.detailAuctionGmodel.getRes().getDetail().getCalculate_end());
                try {
                    sleep(last6RunStartTimer);
                    getlast6BidData();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

**LogCat error :**

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:722)
                                                                            at com.app.android.Fragments.AuctionDetailBidFragment.getlast6BidData(AuctionDetailBidFragment.java:744)
                                                                            at com.app.android.Fragments.AuctionDetailBidFragment.access$100(AuctionDetailBidFragment.java:73)
                                                                            at com.app.android.Fragments.AuctionDetailBidFragment$12.run(AuctionDetailBidFragment.java:737)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: @NileshRathod, can you help me with my codes? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this just check that your thread is alive or not using [**`Thread.isAlive()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) method.

```
private void getlast6BidData() {
        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getUpdateBidsList(Constants.detailAuctionGmodel.getRes().getDetail().getCalculate_end());
                try {
                    sleep(last6RunStartTimer);
                    getlast6BidData();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

       if (!thread.isAlive()){
          thread.start();
       }
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getlast6BidData();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks but not work me and show me again above error :(

Comment: try this also `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` @fghj

Comment: how can use this? can you send to me update code with new help?

Comment: @fghj check updated ans